# Showing different pages depending on a cookie value

Tags: customization, redirect, cookies

I have a website that asks the visitors to choose a language on the first page, I store the option in a cookie and I am showing the content (starting with second page) depending on this option.

I want to show the second page without showing the first one as long as the cookie is not expired.

I try to do something like this in a plugin I made:

```
function has_my_cookie(){

    if ( isset($_COOKIE["myCookie"])) {
        if($_COOKIE["myCookie"] == "en"){
            header("Location:path/to/my/en/file");
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'has_my_cookie');
```

The problem is that I get an infinite loop somewhere (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS).

What am I missing? Is there a better way to achieve this? I tried to do something similar in the header.php, with the same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook into the template redirect function.

```
function my_page_template_redirect() {

    if ( isset( $_COOKIE["myCookie"] ) ) {
        if( $_COOKIE["myCookie"] == "en" ) {            
            wp_redirect( 'you path' );
            exit;
        }
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

And you could better use `wp_redirect()` function to redirect inside Wordpress.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it. I tried wp_redirect as well. No change. I still get the "too_many_redirects" error...

Comment: Could you test the redirect without the cookie code.

Comment: If I try to do a redirect in header.php in my child theme I get this:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...)

Comment: It seems that using the code in header.php at the very beginning of the first php script could do the trick, because any type of output (including a simple non-parsed html tag) will throw the "cannot modify header information..." warning. I'll continue testing and come back with my conclusion.

Comment: Okay let me know if you know more.

Comment: It works as intented ONLY if you add the code at the beginning of the header.php file, before anything else. I consider this question solved.

Comment: Strange.. I think you need to check on bugs in your project then. I am glad I was able to help!